# Do I have to download all my games again if I buy a new PS4 to replace my old one?

Tags: ps4

If I buy a new PS4, and I sign in with my account that I have been using with my old PS4, do I have to download all the games that I had in my old PS4? If yes, will my trophies that I won playing games like GTA5, Minecraft, etc. carry over to my new PS4?

Comment: The next time, put a title that describes yout question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you'll need to redownload the games, but trophies will be saved.

Trophy progress (for trophies that you don't have, but need to do multiple things to win like '1000 kills') may or may not be within the save files that are uploaded to PSN+ if you're a member, and so the progress maybe lost.

You *won't* need to pay again for games you own on PSN. You can download them as many times as you need.

Comment: Not if he takes out the hard drive of his old one.

Comment: Even get 1000 kills should be carried over. Otherwise its an example of incredibly bad coding on the developer's part ...

Comment: @ИвоНедев yes, it *should* but I'd rather point out the fact it might not be due to stupidity, than ignore the fact and have them screaming afterwards!.